# Add Angular 2 sources to WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm developing application on Angular 2 (rc5) and TypeScript (1.8.10).

Angular 2 is written on TypeScript, but in `node_modules` I see `js` with `*.d.ts`. It's too hard looking sources on GitHub.

How can I add sources (in `ts`) for Angular 2 in WebStorm?

Comment: No, it's not available yet. See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22144).

Comment: What kind of sources are you referring to ? some third party libraries ?

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin, thank you. I will watch the issue.

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI, I tried to refer to Angular sources.

Comment: @IlliaSernikov could you show us the source maybe ? one way is to use a seed project and build from there, you could use the official one which is : https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI, project works. But I want to see how implemented, for example, Component decorator for more understanding.  See code sources is my habit :)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to delve into Angular2 source code, you could do that by directly accessing https://github.com/angular/angular